# Water mark Sharepoint Documents?

Tags: document-library, document

How add Water Mark once upload document into the document Library? i checked TITUS is is working but how to achieve without 3rd party tools.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use 3rd party tools. For example, I used the iTextSharp library to add watermarks to my PDF files, and set up a workflow to automatically fire whenever a document is uploaded into the doc library.

Here's a tutorial for the iTextSharp thing.

http://footheory.com/blogs/donnfelker/archive/2008/05/11/using-itextsharp-to-watermark-write-text-to-existing-pdf-s.aspx

Comment: link is outdated, pls put it right

Answer (score -1):

Try this link. It applies to PDFs already uploaded. The watermark gets added on download. 
http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2012/03/stamping-pdf-files-downloaded-from-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/58506)

Comment: Waqas, while I understand your point about links, for me, I wasn't going to copy all the code and claim it as my own. That would imply ownership or at least contribution, of which I did neither. My reply was more of a direction for consideration rather than a certain solution. If that is not the spirit of this website, then I misunderstood the entire concept of "exchange" in StackExchange. -1? Thanks.

Comment: No my dear, concept here is...people will search this answer in future and chances are this url either change or deleted then what information they will get from your reply....what we want, simply copy the essential part from the blog here then put the URL as reference.

Comment: Got it. I'll keep that in mind going forward.

Comment: @Blisteragent, it's what happened to the right answer of rafal-saltarski , the link is broken